Show that $v \in \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dots , e_n).$
Here is the statement I am trying to prove:
Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb R, (e_1, \dots ,e_n)$ is an orthonormal list in $V,$ and $v \in V$ is a vector such that $$||v||^2 = |\langle v, e_1 \rangle|^2 + |\langle v, e_2 \rangle|^2 + \dots + |\langle v, e_n \rangle|^2 \quad \quad \quad (1)$$
Show that $v \in \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dots , e_n).$
My idea:
My idea was to use that $||v||^2 = \langle v , v \rangle $ in $(1.)$ and then get $$\langle v , v \rangle = \langle v, e_1 \rangle \langle v, e_1 \rangle + \langle v, e_2 \rangle \langle v, e_1 \rangle + \dots + \langle v, e_n \rangle \langle v, e_1 \rangle \quad \quad \quad (2)$$ as we are in $\mathbb R$ and then put one of the inner product in each term on the rhs of $(2.)$ in the second coordinate of the other one and then move everything to the lhs and we get the required since $v \neq 0$ and the inner product equals 0 ,but I was told that this is wrong.
Can someone tell me the correct solution please?

why down voting ?

"Here is the question I am trying to prove:" You can't prove a question. You can prove a theorem; you can answer a question; but you can't prove a question.

@GerryMyerson my bad :) I will adjust this

Just compute $| v-\sum_k \langle v, e_k \rangle v_k|^2$. Use the fact that $|w|^2 = \langle w, w \rangle$.

I believe that the idea here might be as follows:
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $v$ is not in the span of the $(e_1, ..., e_n)$. Then since $(e_{n+1}, ..., e_m)$ is orthonormal, we can extend it to an orthonormal basis by adding vectors $w_1,...,w_m$ to the list (this is a fairly standard theorem). Then any vector (in particular, $v$) can be represented as a linear combination of basis elements:
$$v = \sum_{i=0}^{m}a_i e_i$$
But note that then we can write, for each $e_j$,
$$\langle v, e_j\rangle = \left\langle\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}a_i e_i, e_j\right\rangle$$
But as this basis is orthogonormal, we have that $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle = 0$ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ if $i=j$. Thus, we obtain that $a_i = \langle v, e_i\rangle$. But one of the $a_i$ for $i>n$ must be nonzero by assumption, as otherwise we could write $v$ as a linear combination of just the $e_1, ..., e_n$. We now write the squared length of $v$ as
$$||v||^2 = \langle v, v\rangle = \left\langle\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}a_i e_i, \sum_{j=0}^{n+m}a_j e_j\right\rangle$$
By bilinearity we can expand this expression first to
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}a_i \left\langle e_i, \sum_{j=0}^{n+m}a_j e_j\right\rangle$$
and then to
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}a_i\sum_{j=0}^{n+m}a_j \left\langle e_i, e_j\right\rangle$$
But $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle$ is zero if $i\neq j$ and one otherwise, so this simplifies to
\begin{equation}
=\sum_{i=0}^{n+m}a^2_i\end{equation}
However, one of the $a^2_i$ for $i>n$ is nonzero, this sum must be greater than
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i = |\langle v, e_1\rangle|^2 + \dots + |\langle v, e_n\rangle|^2$$
Where the second equality holds as we've already shown $a_i = \langle v, e_i \rangle$. This is a contradiction to the requirement that ||v||^2 = |\langle v, e_1\rangle|^2 + \dots + |\langle v, e_n\rangle|^2$, and so the theorem is proven.

can you please provide all the details in your solution?

Is this sufficient? It looks a lot longer, but that's just because there's a lot of sums. I tried to write out the arguments more or less from scratch, but a lot of these results are standard linear algebra results (for example, that the coefficients in the sum are the inner product with the basis vectors is, imo, fairy standard).

Yes thank you !

Write $W=\text{span}\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ and $W^\perp$ the orthogonal complement of $W$ in $V$. Then $V=W\oplus W^\perp$. Now you can write $v=w+w'$ for unique $w\in W$ and $w'\in W^\perp$. Then $\|v\|^2=\|w\|^2+\|w'\|^2$, where $\|\cdot \|$ is the norm induced by the inner product. Now you have $w=\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\dots \langle v,e_n\rangle e_n$, so that $\|w\|^2=|\langle v,e_1\rangle |^2+\dots+|\langle v,e_n\rangle |^2$. By assumption, $\|v\|^2=\|w\|^2$, so that $\|w'\|^2=0$. Then $w'=0$, so you must have $v=w\in W$.
